# Use of "though" versus "however"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Consider the sentence

> E-books are on the rise, but they haven't suppressed paper books though.

This usage seems to be quite common, but when I learned English  I was taught to use "however" where I now read "though".
My questions on this use of "though" are:

Is this a new trend?
Is it restricted to American English?
Is "though"  considered more colloquial than "however" ?

And on a syntactic level:
Do you put a comma before "though"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use both *but* and *though* together like that, because you're saying the same thing twice; both words mark the clause as antithetical to what came before. So you should **remove one or the other**.

If you decide to use *though*, you **need a comma** before it.

---

I don't know whether it is new; it's just incorrect.

I don't think it is related to American English; I would simply interpret it as a typo, not as a conscious choice.

Both *though* and *however* are a bit informal at the end; *though* is better.
The position of *however* in formal prose is rather at the beginning of a sentence, or after the first constituent.

Answer (score 4):

I thought it might be sensible to list the various acceptable alternatives:

> E-books are on the rise, but they haven't yet totally eliminated the
> demand for paper books.
>
> (Al)though E-books are on the rise, they haven't yet totally
> eliminated the demand for paper books.
>
> E-books are on the rise, (al)though they haven't yet totally
> eliminated the demand for paper books.
>
> E-books are on the rise; they haven't yet totally eliminated the
> demand for paper books, though.
>
> E-books are on the rise; however, they haven't yet totally eliminated
> the demand for paper books.
>
> E-books are on the rise; they haven't yet, however, totally eliminated the
> demand for paper books.
>
> E-books are on the rise; they haven't yet totally eliminated the
> demand for paper books, however.

Comment: Thanks for the list; it doesn't quite answer my question, *though* :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg:  In answer to your question:  No.  There is not a new trend of substituting "though" for "however." Check out the Ngram at the following web page:  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=though%2C+although%2C+however&year_start=1900&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 1):

The only reasonable answer to this question is that you must **DELETE** **though** because it doesn't belong there: it duplicates the function of **but**. *However* would be equally ungrammatical in the sentence:

> E-books are on the rise, **but** they haven't suppressed paper books, **however**.

This sentence is grammatically incorrect.

It's not a new trend. EFL students have been doing it for eons. It's not just an American solecism. All native Anglophones have been infected by the Solecism iVirus (*"i"* for *ignorance*). It's endemic and epidemic wherever English speakers gather.

On a syntactic level:

> **Put a period before "though" and then erase "though"**.

*Common* = *vulgar, crude, rude, inferior, low-grade, mean, poor, second-class, second-rate, shoddy*.